# You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'PRIMERY KEY

Tags: mysql, syntax, primary-key, create-table

I used the following code to create a table on MySQL:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS auth (
  id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
  email VARCHAR(50) UNIQUE NOT NULL PRIMERY KEY,
  password VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
  username VARCHAR(50) UNIQUE,
  admin BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  created_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

But I got this error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'PRIMERY KEY,
  password VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
  username VARCHAR(50) UNIQUE,
```

What is the problem?

`EDIT`: The problem was because of a typo in `PRIMARY KEY`, but after fixing that, I faced another error:

```
ERROR 1075 (42000): Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typo of PRIMERY is an obvious misspelling of PRIMARY. This is something you should have been able to answer yourself.

The second issue is that an auto-increment column must be the first column of a key. Most people say it must be the primary key, but technically it can be any key of the table.

The following table definition works:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS auth (
  id INT UNIQUE AUTO_INCREMENT,
  email VARCHAR(50) PRIMARY KEY,
  password VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
  username VARCHAR(50) UNIQUE,
  admin BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  created_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

Adding `UNIQUE` to the `id` column makes it a key, which satisfies the requirement that the auto-increment column be the first column of a key.

I removed the `UNIQUE NOT NULL` keywords on the `email` column, because that's implied by being `PRIMARY KEY`. It's redundant, and unfortunately MySQL will create an extra unnecessary unique index for `email` if you include both keywords.

Comment: Is it also a redundancy if I write `username VARCHAR(50) UNIQUE NOT NULL`?

Comment: That's fine. `UNIQUE NOT NULL` is not redundant, because UNIQUE normally allows NULLs. `PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL` is redundant because a primary key must be NOT NULL. MySQL makes the columns NOT NULL that whether you specify it or not. You can see it if you run `SHOW CREATE TABLE auth` after you create it, to see how MySQL adjusted your definition.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken you typo'd **PRIMERY KEY** so it should be **PRIMARY KEY**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS auth (
  id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
  email VARCHAR(50) UNIQUE NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  password VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
  username VARCHAR(50) UNIQUE,
  admin BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  created_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

EDIT:
The issue you are getting is because you have an **auto_increment** and **primary key** on different columns. You can use both on 1 column but not on 2 different ones because there can only be 1 auto increment per table.
New script:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS auth (
  id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  email VARCHAR(50) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
  password VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
  username VARCHAR(50) UNIQUE,
  admin BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  created_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

Comment: That's correct!

Comment: But I encountered another error after fixin the previous one!

Comment: @best_of_man i edited the answer for your new issue

Comment: But I want to have both incremental ids and the email as my primary key. There is no way doing that?(unless I do a combined `primary key( id, email)`

Comment: If you add an id with a auto_increment it needs to be part of the primary key.